# Python Check for Variable in another Variable

Tags: python

If trying to compare data from a Text File with data collected from a serial input.
Basically I read 'grain' from a file and send it over the serial port which sends it back for the original sender to confirm it was sent correctly.

In other parts of the code I use:

```
if "AK" in command:
    Do something
```

This finds the letter AK fine and goes into the if but for the next part I basically need:

```
if grain in command:
    Do Something
else:
    Do Something else
```

For some reason it always drops into the else. I'm got the serial port, grain and the buffer (command) all printing out so I can see that grain (A number, normally something like: 22.4) is in command but its not registering in the if loop.

Any ideas of a simple was to do this?

The bit of code in question:
It runs happily but always sends the IC message instead of the AK message at the bottom.

```
file = open("livedata.txt")
grain = file.readline()
air = file.readline()
file.close()

sending=True
send1=True
send2=False
while(sending==True):
    loop=0
    command=''
    serialport.write("1RDRDR1R")
    print ("DR Sent")

    while (loop<30):
        recieved = serialport.read()
        command = command + recieved
        loop = loop+1
    if "BS" in command:
        if "AK" in command:
            while (send1==True):
                serialport.write("1R"+grain+"1R")
                print ("GrainTemp Sent")
                loop=0
                command=''
                while (loop<30):
                    recieved = serialport.read()
                    command = command + recieved
                    loop = loop+1
                if grain in command:
                    serialport.write("1RAKAK1R")
                    print ("GrainTemp AK Sent")
                else:
                    serialport.write("1RICIC1R")
                    print ("GrainTemp IC Sent")
```

Comment: please post your actual code

Comment: Either add `print`s to see the actual content of the variables or use a debugger.

Comment: You are not modifying send1, so you're in an infinite loop reading from the serial port. Is it possible your first output is the AK and scrolls of the screen to fast for you to read? More importantly, are you sure the serial port is echoing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grain = file.readline()
```

includes in string `grain` the **ending newline** so of course it won't be found in another string where there's no such newline immediately after the other content of `grain`.

Use

```
grain = file.readline().strip()
```

to remove whitespace (including newlines) on both sides of `grain` (if there **is** some whitespace in `grain` that's significant to you and you want to match exactly you can do more selective stripping, but it appears from your question that this simple, broad stripping would work for you).